# In which Gundam series does Heroo Yuy appear?

Tags: gundam-series

Which of the *Gundam* anime have the character, Heroo Yuy?

There are so many titles dating from different years, I could not remember the year I watched those before.

Answer (score 4):

His name is obviously *Heero Yuy* as DuckDuckGo and Wikipedia suggest.

[image]

> **Heero Yuy** (ヒイロ・ユイ Hiiro Yui, derived from Japanese hito, lit. "one") is the pilot of the XXXG-01W Wing Gundam and its ancestor/successor, the XXXG-00W0 Wing Gundam Zero. He is the main protagonist of **Mobile Suit Gundam Wing** and of several derivative works that make up the After Colony timeline.

<sup>Source: [Gundam.Wikia.com](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Heero_Yuy)</sup>

Comment: This is a tough one--should I upvote or not? It's a fine answer, but I even typed "Heroo Yuy" (the OP's misspelling) into Google and got the right answer. Well, here, have a +1 anyway.